# Xcode 7 very laggy while editing

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, performance, lag

**Now,I used the latest Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175) in the hope, that the performance will be better and better. But no, performance is much worse again.I feel it since 7.1 to latest**

**My Mac is :** MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6exY6E9SwHeV0RRdUNuLVdnLVk/view

It's running only Xcode
When typing a word, the line of editor so laggy, switching and overlap.
The older version never happened.

**Please watch this :**

https://vimeo.com/165397457

**Are there any fix the problem or the like to tune OS X and Xcode, so it will be more performant. I am using Objective-C as programming language.**

Comment: It's not a problem with your Xcode, you're facing this because, with Xcode 7 they have added more with the package, and it can't handle by your busy RAM. How much RAM you have in your Mac. I guess, default your Mac comes with 4GB. You can upgrade it to 8GB for better performance. I had the same problem so after updating it works smoothly. While having running Chrome, Xcode (two diff projects), Skype etc.

Comment: Thank for answer but my mac is 8GB and now my mac is clean installed with latest OSX El Capitan.

This my mac :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6exY6E9SwHeV0RRdUNuLVdnLVk/view

Previous times, before version 7.1 (estimate) no problem.

Comment: If you have installed any extra softwares that you need stop if running. One thing I notices is chrome is also using many memories on each tabs. So if you don't using information from some tab then consider to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out this discussion for more details :

[Xcode Performance Discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19657)

I suggest you to clean xcode by Command+Shift+K. And Delete xcode build folder and clear all old builds in Organiser window.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank for answer but I try out Command+Shift+K, Delete DerivedData, Delete project.xcworkspace and now my mac is clean installed with latest OSX El Capitan, It still remain. (It not only some project but all projects)